# Suggest an efficient way to extract JSON Data into sObject

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger

Below code works, but i believe there shall be an efficient way to get this data into a single Map,without a need of double for loops to get a individual field value. Please suggest.

```
List<Object> sobjects = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonData);

   for(Object sobj : sobjects)
        {
            sobjectMap = (Map<String,Object>)sobj;
            sObjectMapList.add(sObjectMap);
        }

 for(integer i=0;i < sobjectMapList.size() ;i++)
  {
    Map<String,Object> sObjLstMap = sobjectMapList[i];
    for(String field : sObjLstMap.keySet())
    {
     system.debug('#field Val:' + field + '----------' + sObjLstMap.get(field));
    }
  }
```

Example of JSON data :

```
[  
   {  
      "Opportunity.Probability":"10",
      "Opportunity.StageName":"Prospect",
      "Opportunity.CloseDate":"12/2/2018",
      "Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode":"USD",
      "Opportunity.Name":"Opt1"
   },
   {  
      "Opportunity.Probability":"10",
      "Opportunity.StageName":"Prospect",
      "Opportunity.CloseDate":"12/2/2018",
      "Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode":"USD",
      "Opportunity.Name":"Opt2"
   }
]
```

Comment: do you know a  structure of JSON? Is it not changeable ?

Comment: Structure of JSON, is like a list of Rows from a table.  Its not changeable as its JSON data is an output of a tool that process and gives the data in that format.

Comment: can you update your question with example of JSON?

Comment: sure, updated with an example now.

Comment: actualy, that is not valie JSON...

Comment: I have given an example of converted JSON data into List<SObject>. wont that help.

Comment: can you post content of `jsonData` variable?

Comment: ok, posted now.

Answer (score 4):

When deserializing, the platform gives you the option of:

- Not having to tie down the JSON structure (`JSON.deserializeUntyped`) but then having to write code to walk around the resulting set of nested maps and arrays to pull out the data you are interested in
- Having to tie down the JSON structure up front (`JSON.deserialize`) where the data is stored directly in the typed objects you have supplied - note that https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/ can generate the Apex classes for that - and then just use the instances of those classes or do further work starting from those

However, in your case the names are of the form "Opportunity.Probability" which means you can't use the `JSON.deserialize` approach because for that to work the names must only contain characters that are valid in Apex property names (as an Apex property is defined for each name) and the dot is not.

So that leaves you needing to use `JSON.deserializeUntyped` (unless you can change the JSON) and so having to write code to unpack the data.

Answer (score 1):

yon can to it in one loop like this

```
List<Object> sobjects = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonData);

for(Object sobj : sobjects){
    Map<String,Object> sobjectMap = (Map<String,Object>)sobj;
    for(String field : sobjectMap.keySet()){
        System.debug('field name:' + field + ' field value:' + sobjectMap.get(field));
    }
}
```